# SQL Syntax error near ' 'x')' at line 1 (Insert statement)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, syntax-error, sql-insert

I'm getting problems trying to run this simple sql statement.

```
try{
                            stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO exam_somatique_6_12(id_p, id_m, id_u, Date, age, poids, taille, TA, exam_clinique, acuite_visuelle, acuite_auditive, age_puberte, conclusion) VALUES ("+idpat+","+idmed+","+idum+",'"+currentdate+"',"+txtage.getText()+","+txtpoids.getText()+","+txttaille.getText()+","+txtta.getText()+",'"+Clinique+"','"+Visuelle+"', '"+Auditive+"', "+Signe+", '"+txtobservation.getText()+"')");
                                    }

                                catch(SQLException e1)
                                {
                                    System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
                                }

                            dispose();
```

I have no problem when executing it on mysql, but as soon as I try to do it in Java, I get this message error :

> syntax error near ' 'x')' at line 1

And x is the result of the txtobservation.getText().

Also, I'm pretty sure it's not a quote problem, I'm using ' ' when it's a text, and not doing it when it's an integer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it would be helpful to print the exact query which is being executed

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Then you won't have these problems where munging the string causes syntax problems.

Comment: @shiladitya I didn't want the statement to be too long, that's why I've changed the table's name. Anyway, I've edited it, here's the exact query.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PreparedStatement instead it is more secure and more helpful

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table(id_p, id_m, id_u, Date, age, poids, taille, 
               TA, clinique, visuelle, auditive, puberte, observation) 
               VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query) {

    ps.setInt(1, idpat);//set values to your query
    ps.setInt(2, idmed);
    ....
    ps.executeUpdate();//execute your query
}
```

**Note**
getText it return String and not int and not float if `txtage.getText()` is int you have to convert it to int you can use :

```
Integer.parseInt(txtage.getText());//get int value form a String
Float.parseFloat(txtpoids.getText());//get float value from a String
```

and so on